# how to accept multiple variables in REST API

Tags: php, api, rest, get, slim

i am currenty learning how to use rest api for mobile dev't, i just want to know is there a method for accepting multiple variables in the URL?

for example:

```
$app->get('/chara/arena/:id', 'getArea');
//now this code above can accept only 1 prameter now how do i make it to accept 2 parameters?
```

like:

```
/chara/arena?idA=102&idB=123
```

im using SLIM framework btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i managed to create a solution somehow:
 instead of passing the id of 1 character i pass them at the same time

so if i wanted to pass the id's 1 and 2 i will pass them /chara/battle/1:2
 and use explode like an array.

```
 $app->get('/chara/battle/:mid', 'setArena');

 function setArena($raw_ids){
      $ids = explode(':', $raw_ids);
        $chara_a_id = $ids[0];
        $chara_b_id = $ids[1];
 }
```

i didnt know this can be so simple.

Comment: Or: `list($chara_a_id, $chara_b_id) = explode(':', $raw_ids);`

Comment: i didnt know such function exist, kudos yo you @Madbreaks

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$idA = $app->request()->get('idA');
$idB = $app->request()->get('idB');
```